# Impossible to get information from update manager

Tags: update-manager, repository

When I press the button "check" to find updates, I always get this error:

`Failed to get information from repository`

```bsh
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dylanmccall/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found,    
W:Failed to fetch htp://ppa.launchpad.net/dylanmccall/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found, 
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/dylanmccall/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've noticed that sometimes, in the update manager configuration, there's the same Mexico server instead of Spanish, but if I use the Spanish server, the problem persists.

... And yes, I removed one of the links to be able to post as a new user. (htp = http)

Comment: most of the people do not understand your language. If possible, try to write in english (even if it is bad english), so more people can understand and help you.

Welcome to askubuntu.com!

Comment: Translated it to english.

Comment: By pressing the "check" to check for updates, if you see this error:

Failed to download repository information

......................................

I have noticed that sometimes, in the update manager configuration, the server appears instead of Spanish Mexico but after relocating to Spain the problem persists. And yes, I have removed one of the links to be able to post as a new user. (htp = http

Answer (score 1):

only karmic and maverick are available at this location..
as you can see here.. http://ppa.launchpad.net/dylanmccall/ppa/ubuntu/dists/
so maybe use another location.. or another distribution..

sólo karmic e maverick están disponibles en este lugar .
como se puede ver aquí.. http://ppa.launchpad.net/dylanmccall/ppa/ubuntu/dists/
así que tal vez utilice otro lugar .. u otra distribución ..